# SpringBoot - Controller and RequestMapping always returns 404

Tags: java, spring, rest, maven, spring-boot

I am trying a simplified version of the example [here](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Spring-Boot-2.0-in-7-Days/tree/master/Section%201/HelloWorld). The project was set-up in VSCode with the initializer that comes with the Springboot extension.

**`DemoApplication.java`**

```java
package com.sample.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

**`CalculatorController.java`**

```java
package com.sample.demo;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class CalculatorController {

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String index() {
        return "index";
    }
}
```

I am runming the application from VSCode and accessing it as: `http://localhost:8080/`. I keep getting a `404` error. When I change the `@Controller` annotation to `@RestController` annotation, it works. Also, there exists `resources\templates\index.html`.

What am I missing?

Comment: What's your pom.xml? What's the layout of the project? How did you simplify the example?

Comment: No changes in `pom.xml`; it is same as what was set-up by VSCode. The layout of the project was set-up intializer in VSCode. The simplification is by writing a mapping for `/` only.

Comment: What happens when you run the app using `mvn spring-boot:run`. And please, can you **post** your pom.xml and **post** the layout of the project? Saying that you set it up in VSCode doesn't tell us what it is.

Comment: This is the POM: https://pastebin.com/BCfbXKnD `mvn` runs clean as I can see that Tomcat has started and is listening at `8080`.

Comment: Project layout is same as here: https://miro.medium.com/max/590/1*6y3YcuyKL6RaF0DJGy4uPw.png

Comment: So, what happens when you run  the app using mvn spring-boot:run **and test your app**?

Comment: OK. The pom is **not** identical to the pom in the example. You have missing dependencies.

Comment: Yes, I missed the one for `thymeleaf` - let me try again.

Comment: Thymeleaf probably includes Spring MVC within it.

Comment: With `thymeleaf` included, its working now! Please add your comment as answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 0):

The context is a very high overview of  spring MVC is designed with Front Controller design pattern where Dispatcher servlet will receive all the requests and invoke the corresponding handler so that your controller method is called is your controller class is annotated with 
@Controller annoation dispatcher servlet considered that return value and try to locate View in your MVC so that you need to configure any one of implementations of ViewResolver in your case you need to configure InternalResourceViewResolver and Themeleaf with corresponding view locations.

if your controllers is annotated with @RestController return value of the handler will be as considered as Http response Dispatcher servlet will not look any views(it will considered return value  as http response body)

you can achieve same thing with @Controller annotation itself simple add this annoation @ResponseBody in your handler method(return value is considered as http response).

Answer (score 0):

The @RestController annotation in Spring MVC is nothing but a combination of @Controller and @ResponseBody annotation. It was added into Spring 4.0 to make the development of RESTful Web Services in Spring framework easier.

The job of @Controller is to create a Map of model object and find a view but @RestController simply return the object and object data is directly written into HTTP response as JSON or XML.

```
@SuppressWarnings({})
@RestController
public class TestController {
    @PostMapping("/test/1")
    public Object Test1(@RequestBody HashMap<String, String> obj) throws ParseException, IOException {
        return null;
    }
```

Read more: https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2017/08/difference-between-restcontroller-and-controller-annotations-spring-mvc-rest.html#ixzz62Jw1WOs3

Answer (score 0):

@RestController is combination of @Controller and @ResponseBody.So request handling method returns objects into HttpResponse as Json or XML, therefore @ResponseBody isn't required.

```
@RestController
public class UserRestController { }

@Controller
@ResponseBody
public class UserController { }
```

@ResponseBody is a Spring annotation which binds a method which return value to web response body.It tells a controller that the object returned is automatically serialized into JSON and passed back into the HttpResponse object.